# Metaball texture grid

Tags: procedural, shader-nodes

I'm trying to make something similar to this:

[image: hofmann-typeface]

(http://www.davidgobber.com/content/work/14-hofmann-typeface/hofmann_typeface_06.jpg)

But where the combined shape is filled and the dots in the grid are invisible (the image is just for reference of how the "system" works).

I've started doing the grid and thought that a "metaball" effect would be a good starting point (if anyone has a better idea about how to achieve this I'm all ears):

[image]

My problem is that I can achieve the effect when having separate objects, but when doing the Voronoi texture grid the effect doesn't work? What am I missing here?

Additional info:

I followed this tutorial of *Default Cube* ([2D Metaballs](http://youtube.com/watch?v=4JT_43qc0Dc&t=461s)) to achieve the metaball effect. But when distributing the points in a grid with help of a Voronoi Texture the effect doesn't work anymore.

I know this isn't really close to the outcome that I want in the end. This is just a starting point for me to figure out how to merge the shapes based on proximity.

Comment: How do you *"achieve the effect when having separate objects"*? How do you define which point merges with which other point? When you use real metaballs then the tip of the "S" would merge with the curve which it touches and you would end up with a "9". And this "E" in the screenshot above will become a "6".

Comment: I followed this tutorial to achieve the metaball effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JT_43qc0Dc&t=461s but when distributing the points in a grid the effect doesn't work anymore.

I know this isn't really close to the outcome that I wan't in the end. This is just a starting point for me to figure out how to merge the shapes based on proximity.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. But in fact, it works. What you see is 9 balls merged with 9 balls on the same spot which results in 9 bigger balls. If you duplicate the Voronoi and the Mapping nodes and use them for the Smooth (Math) node with a lower Distance value (0.1) and then change the X location value for the Mapping node you will see the metaball effect.

Comment: To create a letter in this grid you need the information of which ball is active (one node for each ball?) and with which other balls is it allowed to merge (layers?). But there still will be the problem when the balls that are not right next to each other should merge. E.g. the middle part of the "S" or the "E" or the left bottom part of the "U". Maybe use a smaller ball for the "in between" connection?

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work when i change the x location, but if I rotate one of the circle grids it works? But thanks anyway! I'll try and separate the circles and randomise which are visible. I know that there are a lot of steps to be able to recreate the symbols in the first post. But I'm just trying to get something similar where the ones that are closest to each other merge.